# Sprockets::FileNotFound when trying to include a jQuery gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, tablesorter, assets, sprockets

I'm trying to use https://github.com/linjunpop/jquery-tablesorter-rails to sort my tables. I'm running into issues when trying to include the CSS:

```
 /*
 * = require jquery-tablesorter/blue
 */
```

Error message:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-tablesorter/blue'
```

I do see the Gem being loaded in the config path:

```
1.9.3p194 :008 > Rails.application.config.assets.paths.each { |x| puts x }
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jquery-tablesorter-1.0.5/vendor/assets/images
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jquery-tablesorter-1.0.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/jquery-tablesorter-1.0.5/vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: I believe is *= require jquery-tablesorter/theme.blue

Answer (score 3):

Can't reproduce. Usually when this kind of things happen to me is because of forgetting to restart the dev server after bundling a new gem. Sprockets tries to build or resolve a new set of assets, but the loaded environment is the same as before, so the additional asset can't be found.

Comment: It is important to always restart your server when adding gems that affect your assets, I think. I ran into the same issue (without the typo in code), and found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The corret path is:

```
*= require jquery-tablesorter/theme.blue
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Tablesorter to use themes in version 2.4+, so the blue theme file has been renamed and moved to a different directory.

I don't know much about Ruby, or that repo but you might want to get [Tablesorter v2.3.11](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/tags) until that repo has been updated (see [this issue](https://github.com/linjunpop/jquery-tablesorter-rails/issues/5) in that repo).

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the path you're requiring [as a directory](https://github.com/linjunpop/jquery-tablesorter-rails/tree/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery-tablesorter/blue); the error message seems to indicate that it's failing to find a file. Have you tried

```
*= require jquery-tablesorter/blue/*
```

instead?